# Can we have question/comment functionality on the Data Explorer?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

The [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) is great. But there seems to be no natural place to request modifications to a given query or to request a desired new query.

If we had at least comment functionality, we could ask the script-writer for a simple change. And we could also propose improvements or link to improved versions of the query.

But even more useful would be a natural forum where one could make wish-list requests for queries. Why doesn't the Data Explorer follow something closer to the standard StackExchange question/answer/voting/comment format?

Comment: Aside: every Data Explorer query has a *fork query* button so that you can make changes to fit your needs.

Comment: I suppose that way I could explore all manner of syntax error and mistaken programming methods while I'm waiting...

Comment: I guess you want something like http://stackapps.com/ for Data Explorer.

Answer (score 4):

I found these questions on meta.SE:

- [Where can you discuss or ask for comments on a data explorer query?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91086/where-can-you-discuss-or-ask-for-comments-on-a-data-explorer-query)
- [Where do I ask questions about data explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107137/where-do-i-ask-questions-about-data-explorer)

Based on the answers provided there, it seems that [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) is the place for asking questions like that and that ([data-explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer)) is recommended tag for such questions.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I had suspected that this might be the recommended practice, but I don't think that this mechanism provides the desired functionality, so I'll let my feature-request stand. If I should want to make a technical comment on someone's query, it would seem absurd for me to make a post on meta.SO in the hope that they see it there. Why not just allow comments directly on the Data Explorer?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but similar feature request at meta.SO: [Can we have a feature to allow commenting on Data Explorer queries?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87531/can-we-have-a-feature-to-allow-commenting-on-data-explorer-queries)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Perhaps one possibility would be to ping the creator of the query on some site where he is active to attract him to the post on SO or to discussion on chat. However, it might not be always easy to find the creator of the query. I have posted this on meta.SO, we will see whether there will be some reasonable suggestions: [How can we identify the creator of Data Explorer query?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204142/how-can-we-identify-the-creator-of-data-explorer-query)